# Conditional blocks are executing after executing all the prompts inside a field in vxml

Tags: vxml

[sample_vxml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BrQ3.png)

```
            <if cond="00==1">
                <prompt><audio src="http://127.0.0.1/ivr/audio/en/cent.wav"/></prompt>
            <else/>
                <prompt><audio src="http://127.0.0.1/ivr/audio/en/cents.wav"/></prompt>
            </if>   
                    <prompt><audio src="http://127.0.0.1/ivr/audio/en/break500.wav"/> </prompt>
                    <prompt><audio src="http://127.0.0.1/ivr/audio/en/Press_3.wav"/> </prompt>
                    <prompt><audio src="http://127.0.0.1/ivr/audio/en/to_pay_your.wav"/> </prompt>
                    <prompt><audio src="http://127.0.0.1/ivr/audio/en/curr_stmt_bal_amt.wav"/> </prompt>
```

above the conditional block in the field tag is executing after all the prompt tags are executed.after "" this prompt it should play either cent.wav or cents.wav then it should play the remaining prompts after conditional block but it is entering into conditional block after all other prompts executed. can anyone suggest how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Is this all within the same block or field?  Can you provide a broader context of the VoiceXML document? The Form interpretation algorithm triggers an order than can sometimes be unexpected.

Comment: with in the field only

Comment: it is going to the conditional block but the prompt is playing after playing other prompts inside the field

Answer (score 0):

You are using `<if>` in a parent that is not allowed, you can only use `<if>` inside the tags.

```
<block>, <catch>, <error>, <filled>, <foreach>, <help>, <if>, <noinput>, <nomatch>
```

You will have to create a variable with the locution that you want to give in a `<block>` before the `<field>` in the same `<form>`, for example.
There are a few places where it is documented as:- [**Dialogic**](https://www.dialogic.com/webhelp/XMS/2.0/XMS_VXMLRef/if.html)